# Why is eMMC in a BGA package, despite only using a small number of pins?

Tags: pcb, bga

eMMC comes in BGA packages with many pins (100-200), yet it only uses a few of them (10-30).  Why doesn't it come in a package with fewer pins instead, as wouldn't this be cheaper and easier to fit/inspect?

The BGA 153 pinout (designed by committee) can be found in [this blog post](https://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=37268).

Comment: Please provide a hyper link to the device’s data sheet.

Comment: A bit of speculation; I have used eMMC and there are various physical package sizes (and accordingly number of balls) due to die size requirements; as the attach strength is strongly related to balls per square area for a BGA, a fairly full grid makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having all data pins in roughly one place (as opposed to being distributed around the chip) makes it easier to design the PCB as all traces tend to have the same length (and thus the same propagation time) naturally.

BGA packages also have very low pin inductance values, which are desirable for high frequency operation, even if the required number of pins is low.

Once you decide to go for a BGA package (because of the two factors above), you don't really have an option to only make the pads you need for the signals. Uneven pad distribution would lead to reflow defects, poor thermal conductivity and increased mechanical stress during reflow and operation.

Answer (score 3):

The size of the eMMC package is limited by the size of the silicon chip inside the package. Its size can't be reduced (with current available technology).

The number of pins could be reduced, yes, but it would also make it mechanically weaker, because the package would still be fairly large. There needs to be enough pins to keep the package mechanically connected to the PCB.

Comment: The structural integrity of ICs is provided by the lead frame, not the pins. The pins are attached to the die using tiny bond wires.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - the *effective board attach strength* is strongly influenced by the number of balls for a BGA (or more strictly the number of balls per square area) and *may* be one reason the package in question uses so many.

Comment: +1 It's for a portable handheld device (cell phone) so mechanical strength of the PCB-BGA is pretty important.

Comment: Do you have any references that could back up this answer?

Comment: @PeterSmith I assumed "a package with fewer pins instead" meant a SOIC/QFP or something similar. A large BGA with 10-30 pins simply makes no sense.

Comment: These things are going into tiny devices, so small, low-profile packages are an absolute must. No way can they use a TSSOP or SOIC or any leaded package. It is not just the XY area but the Z-height. I believe the BGA is actually a chip-scale package, just as TemeV says. For sure it is lower than any leaded package.